# Messages with expired event time causing java heap space OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am running a job with a normal tumbling event time window (window size of 1 hour). After running long enough, it will throw an error about the java heap running out of space. Now the thing about the data that is being processed is that there will be one message that occurs today at noon and the next 15k or so will be from a week prior (this isn't how the data is expected to always be, but it should be handled either way). So the watermark is well past the time of the event times of the next 15k messages, even with allowable lateness, so the late messages should be discarded. Or at least that is what I thought since they are no longer in that window.

So my question is this. Does Flink maintain messages that are expired even though they aren't used by the window? Or is it just for their tumbling window and there is something else or some property I should be setting to make sure that expired data doesn't eat up memory?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

```
DataStream<OutputObject> outputStream = sourceData
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<Record>(Time.minutes(1)) {
        @Override
        public long extractTimestamp(Record record) {
            long eventTimeFromRecord = record.eventTimestamp;

            return eventTimeFromRecord;
        }
    })
    .keyBy("fieldToKeyBy")
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(1)))
    .apply(new ApplyFunction());
```

Comment: It depends. For example, if you are using per-partition watermarking with Kafka, then a single event won't advance the current watermark for the entire job.  Maybe share a bit more of the code or overall app logic?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I updated the question with a code example.

Comment: I see that you have setup watermarking and are using TumblingEventTimeWindows, but did you set the time characteristic to event time?

Comment: Yes, I have set the time characteristic to event time.

Comment: What is the parallelism of the source? A single event from now is not enough to advance the watermark for all parallel instances of a parallel source -- it could be that the watermark is not behaving in the way you expect.

Comment: parallelism 3 and it's not that the watermark isn't advancing. The situation is like this. The data is flowing through and the watermark is at: 
"2017-10-15 12:00:00". 
Now there is a window open waiting for valid data, but all the messages that are coming in from the source now is late (let's say they all have event times of 2017-10-05 08:00:00). Now I would expect that because the event time of the messages is extremely late that they would be ignored/dropped immediately since they don't fit into any window, but the memory eventually runs out like they are being kept in memory anyway.

Comment: Sorry to harp on this, but it remains the most obvious explanation. If the source has a parallelism of 3, then there are 3 watermarks, and if any one of them is way back in the past somewhere then the otherwise late events will be processed by whichever nodes haven't advanced their watermarks. You said there was "one message that occurs today at noon" -- one message isn't enough to advance all three watermarks. Also keep in mind that watermarks aren't stored in checkpoints or savepoints, so you can't count on message traffic from a previous job to have brought the watermarks up to date.

Comment: The window assigner will create ephemeral window objects for these late events, but events that are late with respect to the watermark and the allowed lateness won't be stored in those windows, and if those windows remain empty they won't stick around -- they will be immediately garbage collected.

Comment: Ohh ok I see what you are saying, @alpinegizmo. That makes sense and I completely follow. I have been assuming that all the late events are keyed to go to a window that is already advanced, but it could very well be they are just going to another window whose watermark hasn't advanced that far, thus they are not late for that window. I will look into it more to see if that is the case, but I suspect it is. Thanks for bearing with me haha. If you want to make that an answer I will mark it as such as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a source has parallelism of n, then there are n watermarks -- one for each of the parallel sub-tasks. In a case where a Flink job receives one message timestamped today at noon, followed by many events from a week ago, that one message will only advance the watermark for one of the parallel tasks, and the other n-1 tasks will still have Long.min_value as their watermark. So those "late" events will only be recognized as late in one of the parallel window operators, and the other n-1 windows will go ahead and process those "late" events.

Note this could also happen if you had just restored from a checkpoint or savepoint, because watermarks aren't saved in checkpoints or savepoints. This means you can't count on message traffic from a previous job to have brought the watermarks up to date.